# Clean HTML tags from Tags results truncated text

Tags: joomla-4.x

When you click a Tag you are directed to Tags results that are rendered by ../components/com_tags/tag/default_items.php.
By overriding this file you can have your specific look.
A serious issue with the above file is the rendering of the truncated text that has HTML tags and this can result in a breaking layout. For example, if you have an opening Unordered List tag without the closing tag, a usual issue, that breaks the whole layout.

The code (in Joomla 4) that displays the truncated text from the main article text is:

```
<?php echo HTMLHelper::_('string.truncate', $item->core_body, $this->params->get('tag_list_item_maximum_characters')); ?>
```

So, the question is: How can we modify the above code to strip HTML tags?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but there's an option to strip tags. The allowHtml function's parameter set to false will strip tags <strike>I guess.</strike> I'm sure.
https://api.joomla.org/cms-4/classes/Joomla-CMS-HTML-Helpers-StringHelper.html#method_truncate

```
<?php echo HTMLHelper::_('string.truncate', $item->core_body, $this->params->get('tag_list_item_maximum_characters'),true, false ); ?>
```

The last argument is for allow or not HTML, in your case set to false will remove all tags.

Comment: any idea how to implement this on my specific code?

Comment: The function is: truncate(string text, int length, bool noSplit = true, bool allowHtml = true) : string
you can use allowHtml = false